# What exactly is the benifit of using Punjab

Tags: python, xmpp

I've been working with XMPP related stuff now and here's what I've assimilated so far. XMPP and HTTP are two different protocols but when you're trying to implement a browser-based XMPP client, the XMPP traffic would piggyback on HTTP which is called XMPP-over-BOSH.

I came across  Punjab which seems to be a pretty popular XMPP/BOSH connection manager and works with the common XMPP servers like ejabberd and OpenFire. These common XMPP servers like ejabberd and Openfire already seem to have inbuilt support for XMPP-over-BOSH therefore, what added functionality does Punjab provide.

Many large sites are using Punjab in their XMPP implementation but I couldn't figure out why they would be using it when you could directly have the in-broswe XMPP client connect to ejabberd or OpenFire.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the servers with direct BOSH support did not have that support early on.  It's also sometimes handy to move the BOSH proxy closer to your web infrastructure, particularly before [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) was as well-understood.

Comment: Hi Joe, would it be possible for you to elaborate on as how having the BOSH connection manager neared to the web infrastructure might be useful. If you know a good example, it would be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Start by reading the CORS spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/), and understanding why cross-origin scripting can be dangerous without explicit authorization.